# Motherboard storage drivers confusion

Tags: windows-7, drivers, storage

I'm always confused when I need to install the MOBO drivers for storage. Eg: for my mobo, there are 5 different drivers for storage. It is not clear what they do and which one I need to install!!

Can someone please clarify for what those 5 drivers are for? Do I need all of them or only one? Those are the most updated versions or I can find newer on Intel's webpage?

Eg:

[image: Storage drivers list]

Link for the download page:
http://www.asus.com/ROG_ROG/RAMPAGE_III_EXTREME/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: I only see three drivers.  The current version of the Marvel driver, the current version of Intel's RSTD driver, and the current version of Intel's MMD.

Comment: MMD is only required for RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Your motherboard features multiple storage controllers (Intel, Marvell).

For the Intel controller install:

- Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology Driver Software V10.5.0.1026 for Windows Vista/7 32bit & 64bit(WHQL)

For the Marvell one just install the newest version, you dont need the old ones:

- Marvell Controller Driver V1.0.0.1045 for Windows XP/Vista/Win7 32bit&64bit(WHQL)